# pinescript strategy - different result after script translation v2>v5

Tags: pine-script-v5

[v2vsv5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZIAc.gif)i have a simple script ,  translate the version from v2 > v5 , it should be sucess and work on new ver.v5  but i face a problem that , the strategy entry/exit time is totally different after translate.(refer to photo,should clearly show the different)  i double check the script and setting, should be no bug. (you can see the quantity of trade no. are same)

what i guess and want---

> is it possible there is problem,some of internal-pine-script-fuction - logic which is different from v5 vs v2?
> How to modify the v5 version script in order to get the same result(same strategy entry/exit time) with v2?

Printscreen here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiUzx.gif
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiUzx.gif
v2 script:

```
    '//Heikin Ashi Strategy 
strategy("Heikin Ashi",shorttitle="HA_R01",overlay=true,default_qty_value=1000,initial_capital=100000,currency=currency.USD)
res = input(title="Heikin Ashi Candle Time Frame", type=resolution, defval="1440")
hshift = input(0,title="Heikin Ashi Candle Time Frame Shift")
//Heikin Ashi Open/Close Price
ha_t = heikinashi(tickerid)
ha_open = security(ha_t, res, open[hshift])
ha_close = security(ha_t, res, close[hshift])
//Strategy
golong =  (ha_close > ha_open )
goshort =   (ha_close < ha_open )

strategy.entry("Buy",strategy.long,when = golong)
strategy.entry("Sell",strategy.short,when = goshort)
```

v5 script:

```
//Heikin Ashi Strategy 
//@version=5
strategy("Heikin Ashiv5",shorttitle="HA_R01v5",overlay=true,default_qty_value=1000,initial_capital=100000,currency=currency.USD)
res = input.timeframe(title="Heikin Ashi Candle Time Frame", defval="D")
hshift = input(0,title="Heikin Ashi Candle Time Frame Shift")
//Heikin Ashi Open/Close Price
ha_t =  ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid)
ha_open = request.security(ha_t, res, open[hshift])
ha_close = request.security(ha_t, res, close[hshift])
//Strategy
golong =  (ha_close > ha_open )
goshort =   (ha_close < ha_open )

strategy.entry("Buy",strategy.long,when = golong)
strategy.entry("Sell",strategy.short,when = goshort)here
```

Comment: anyone have ideas?